# Parse HTML and look for multiple classes and tags - most elegant way?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

Currently I have the following code:

```
author_name = soup.find(True, {"class":["author", "author-name"]}) 
    if author_name is not None:
        print author_name.text
    else:
        author_name = soup.find(rel="author")
        if author_name is not None:
            print author_name.text
        else:
            print "No Author Found"
```

I am trying to find the author of an article. Thus I look through the classes for entries like `class="author"`, `class="author-name"`, etc... or `rel=author` and so forth. If I do it the way I did it will end up in alot of different `if` and `else` statements. This does not seem very elegant to me, even though I just recently started coding. Could you guys help me out on how to do this much more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors); these let you specify multiple selection criteria in one string:

```
soup.select('.author, .author-name, [rel="author"]')
```

This produces a *list*, looping would give you the option to find one most to your liking perhaps, or you could just use the `next()` function to get the first:

```
for candidate in soup.select('.author, .author-name, [rel="author"]'):
    if candidate.text:
        author = candidate.text
        break
else:
    print "No author found"
```

The `soup.select()` call will include any elements that match in document order, so the above will find the first qualifying element regardless of how it qualified; it won't prefer `.author-name` over tags with `rel="author"` if the latter is found in the document first.

Answer (score 0):

This how i would do it:

```
results = []
results += soup.select('.author')
results += soup.select('.author-name') 
results += soup.select('[rel=author]')
```